# Append to several lists inside list

Tags: python, list, append

I have an empty list of empty lists defined like so:

```
lis_A = [[], [], []]
```

to which I need, at some point in my code, to append values recursively like so:

```
lis_A[0].append(some_value0)
lis_A[1].append(some_value1)
lis_A[2].append(some_value2)
```

so it looks like this:

```
print lis_A
[[some_value0], [some_value1], [some_value2]]
```

What is the pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: how are those values related? `some_Value0`, `some_Value1`..?

Comment: They are unrelated and obtained from some other process. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Then please show the code. How are you getting those values?

Comment: I'm getting the values from different processes (reading a value in a file, making some calculations with a defined function, etc..), the code itself is irrelevant. All values are numbers and are completely unrelated to one another. Just pretend they are random numbers? How is the process by which I obtain those values relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> lis_A = [[], [], []]
>>> vals = [1,2,3]
>>> [x.append(y) for x, y in zip(lis_A, vals)]
>>> lis_A
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Or if you wan't a fast for loop without side effects use:

```
from itertools import izip

for x, y in izip(lis_A, vals):
    x.append(y)
```

Comment: A list comprehension isn't a good idea in this case, you're iterating over the list for the _effect_ not for the _value_. Proof of this is the intermediate list of `None` created in the third line that gets wasted. Using a simple `for` is preferred

Comment: @ÓscarLópez If you want to avoid the side effect and use a for loop you should use: `for x, y in izip(lis_A, vals): x.append(y)`. It's 50% faster than `enumerate` version.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lis_A = [[], [], []]
to_append = [1, 2, 3]

for i, e in enumerate(to_append):
    lis_A[i].append(e)

lis_A
=> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

If there's more than one element to append to each sublist, this will work as long as the `to_append` list is constructed with care:

```
lis_A = [[], [], []]
to_append = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

for i, e in enumerate(to_append):
    lis_A[i % len(lis_A)].append(e)

lis_A
=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
my_lists = {}
for key, some_value in process_result():
    my_list = my_lists.get(key, [])
    my_list.append(some_value)
    my_lists[key] = my_list
```

There's probably some value for `key` that make sense, other than `0, 1, 2`.